# Get details about videos from album

Tags: objective-c

I am getting all videos from custom album in my app and i need to show those videos into a UICollectionView.

I was able to get the videos to an array and to show the thumbnail of the video ..

How can i get the details of the videos for example: video duration, date of the recording, etc ..

This is how i got the videos from a specific album

```
assets = [NSMutableArray new];
_library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

[_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){

    if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqual:@"Custom App Album"]) {

        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];

            if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])  {
                NSLog(@"asset: %@", result);

                [assets addObject:result];
            }

            [_collectionView reloadData];

        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

And this is how i displayed the thumbnail,

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GalleryCell *galleryCell = (GalleryCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GalleryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ALAsset *alasset = [assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    galleryCell.videoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:alasset.thumbnail];

    return  galleryCell;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: programmatically you can't... you have to have webservice for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet from React Native. You can get the details from the result and group.

```
      CGSize dimensions = [result defaultRepresentation].dimensions;
      CLLocation *loc = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
      NSDate *date = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
      [assets addObject:@{
                          @"node": @{
                              @"type": [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType],
                              @"group_name": [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName],
                              @"image": @{
                                  @"uri": uri,
                                  @"height": @(dimensions.height),
                                  @"width": @(dimensions.width),
                                  @"isStored": @YES,
                                  },
                              @"timestamp": @(date.timeIntervalSince1970),
                              @"location": loc ?
                              @{
                                @"latitude": @(loc.coordinate.latitude),
                                @"longitude": @(loc.coordinate.longitude),
                                @"altitude": @(loc.altitude),
                                @"heading": @(loc.course),
                                @"speed": @(loc.speed),
                                } : @{},
                              }
                          }];
```